# PHP: preg_match - "Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash"

Tags: php, regex

Does anyone know what is wrong with this regex? It works fine on sites like RegexPal and RegExr, but in PHP it gives me this warning and no results:

```
Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash
```

Here's my code:

```
preg_match('name="dsh" id="dsh" value="(.*?)"', 'name="dsh" id="dsh" value="123"', $matches);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have no delimiter. Enclose the pattern in `/`

```
preg_match('/name="dsh" id="dsh" value="(.*?)"/', 'name="dsh" id="dsh" value="123"', $matches);
```

For patterns that include `/` on their own, it is advisable to use a different delimiter like `~`  or `#` to avoid escaping:

```
// Delimited with # instead of /
preg_match('#name="dsh" id="dsh" value="(.*?)"#', 'name="dsh" id="dsh" value="123"', $matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need [delimiters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php):

```
preg_match('/name="dsh" id="dsh" value="(.*?)"/', 'name="dsh" id="dsh" value="123"', $matches);
```